# Proving a Discrete Mathematics equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to prove the following 2 equations: 
A,B are subsets of a group U

> A ⊕ ∅ = A
>   
>   now as I understood this equation means
>   {a,∅},{b,∅}... if a,b -> A 
>   Right?
>    
>   Second equation is
>
> (A ⊕ B) ⊕ B = A

I think if I would understand the method on one of them,
 I'll understand it
on the other

Comment: Do you have a definition of the $\oplus$ symbol?

Comment: The question is unclear: your first equation is missing $B$ and you haven't defined the circled plus, which you should do for a homework question. If you're having trouble with math formatting and don't know LaTeX, I suggest writing your question out in words. This post [How do I type math in my question/answer/comment?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange) was helpful for me--it's from the FAQ.

Comment: Also, are you working with groups (an algebraic structure) or simply with sets? The two questions make sense if $A\oplus B$ means the symmetric difference $(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$, but your "$\{a,\varnothing\},\{b,\varnothing\},\ldots$" could suggest that you're confusing it with direct sums.

Comment: Asaf, if you want to write the name of $\oplus$ in Hebrew and I could translate it to the proper term. Do you mean הפרש סימטרי, also known as symmetric difference and "xor"?

Comment: I also note that you used "group" which can be the naive translation of קבוצה, however it is not the correct term. Group is a distinct concept translated as חבורה.

Comment: ⊕ Symmetric difference

Comment: I actually used "group" from the word Menge (german), although the word קבוצה is in fact the word I'm looking for (having studied this subject in hebrew as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, $A⊕B=(A\setminus B) \cup ( B \setminus A).$

Well, let's use it on your examples :)

$$A⊕\varnothing=(A\setminus \varnothing) \cup (\varnothing \setminus A)=A\cup\varnothing=A$$

$$(A⊕B)⊕B=((A\setminus B) \cup ( B \setminus A))⊕B=$$
$$(((A\setminus B) \cup ( B \setminus A))\setminus B)\cup(B \setminus((A\setminus B) \cup ( B \setminus A)))=$$
$$(A \setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)=A$$

Answer (score 1):

The simplest definition I know of symmetric set difference is
$$
x \in A \oplus B \;\equiv\; x \in A \not\equiv x \in B
$$
Using this, we can calculate the elements of the left hand side of first equality, as follows:
\begin{align}
& x \in A \oplus \varnothing \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\oplus\;$"} \\
& x \in A \not\equiv x \in \varnothing \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\varnothing\;$"} \\
& x \in A \not\equiv \text{false} \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& x \in A \\
\end{align}
By set extensionality this proves the first equality.

To prove the second, we calculate similarly
\begin{align}
& x \in (A \oplus B) \oplus B \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\oplus\;$, twice; drop parentheses since $\;\not\equiv\;$ is associative"} \\
& x \in A \not\equiv x \in B \not\equiv x \in B \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& x \in A \not\equiv \text{false} \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& x \in A \\
\end{align}